# Ubuntu service not logging errors in a different file

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

I have created a Telegram bot using Java and I'm hosting it in an Ubuntu server.

I configured the service with the following code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Telegram bot service daemon

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Telegram
ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /home/ubuntu/Telegram/errorlog
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/Telegram/TelegramBot.jar

StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/Telegram/log
StandardError=file:/home/ubuntu/Telegram/errorlog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see, `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` files are set to be different but when I start the daemon, I see that all the Java exceptions that occur, are logged in the `log` file instead of the `errorlog` file (which is always empty).

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Tangentially, weird to run a system service in a regular user's home directory.

Comment: @tripleee what would be the "traditional" directory to store the executable of a system service that needs some files in the directory the executable is in?

Comment: That's not how it's traditionally done. Binary in `/usr/local/bin`, data in `/usr/local/share/yourservice`